# How to call an asyncio coroutine from Celery

Tags: python, celery, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I'm implementing a celery queue-worker system, but I want to be able to call an existing library function/coroutine that is marked `async`. I'm getting OSErrors with `loop.run_until_complete()` which I assume is from trying to run event loops in a non-single threaded manner.

```
import asyncio
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('blah', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

async def async_func():
    asyncio.sleep(20)

@app.task
def task():
    # what do I do here to run async_func?
    pass
```

Comment: Oo thanks for this. `call_soon[_threadsafe]` doesn't work for me because I think the worker just moves onto the next task, and nothing blocks for the coroutine so it never gets called. I might just create another event loop for now. It feels dirty but it seems like it will work